# Backbone Model: Is there a way to differentiate the inital save event from subsequent ones?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-events

The title of the question pretty much sums it up, I'd like my view to respond differently to a model instances initial save vs any future saves. Right now I'm grabbing the model's `isNew` attr before I save and then triggering a custom event, but I was wondering if there was anything built in?

Comment: The only thing built in is the request format is different - it's a POST for the first save and PUTs for the others. Try overriding `backbone.sync` or 'peek into the source code' to get some idea

Comment: Thanks that works. Is there a way to override Backbone.sync and somehow save its previous functionality (other than completely copying the code and adding your own stuff). Kind of like when you invoke super on a superclass in Java?

Comment: Asked elsewhere and solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770082/override-backbone-sync-but-save-its-previous-functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770082/override-backbone-sync-but-save-its-previous-functionality), I came up with the following solution:

```
var originalSync = Backbone.sync;
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    console.log(method);
    originalSync.apply(Backbone, [method, model, options]);
};
```

I can now check what `method` is being called.

Answer (score 4):

Checking `model.isNew()` is the built-in way of telling whether the initial save has happened yet. If checking `isNew` is working for you, keep on doing it.

The initial save should issue an ID for the object, so you could bind a function to "change:id" and it would execute after the initial save succeeds. Or you could add logic to the "success" and "error" callbacks of `create()`.